# ReST resource/model with optional fields

Tags: java, json, rest, post, jax-rs

I am trying to learn how to implement a CRUD ReST API. I created a simple application using JAX-RS and am testing my HTTP methods using Postman. My question is, how do I define optional fields for a model for POST method?

ex. Person contains firstName, lastName as required fields, and age, gender as optional fields.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Person {

private long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public Person() {}

public Person(long id, String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

//getter and setters omitted
```

Above is a sub-resource to another resource, and below addPerson service method is used to POST to a HashMap.

```
public Person addPerson(long userId, Person person) {
    Map<Long, Person> persons = users.get(userId).getPersons();
    person.setId(persons.size() + 1);
    persons.put(person.getId(), person);

    return person;
}
```

I thought of constructing a model whose constructor has multiple different combination of parameters to instantiate a model class, but that doesn't seem very efficient. Can somebody advise?

FURTHER EDIT: This needs to be done while processing JSON. Given two JSON formatted request:

```
{
 "firstName": "Jay",
 "lastName": "Kay",
 "age": "13"
}
```

and

```
{
 "firstName": "Jay",
 "lastName": "Kay"
 }
```

both should be processable since age(as well as gender) is an "optional attributes" so it may be either omitted, or have a value. I'm coming across JSON parsers and trying to read through them since that may be an answer to processing such requests.

Comment: Can you provide your model and resource classes?

Comment: @JoPeyper I've added edits to show some examples. Let me know if above makes sense? Thank you!

Comment: The last line is still not clear to me. Exactly WHAT are you trying to process from JSON?

Comment: @AnandUndavia I've added further edits to clarify what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm new to ReST so I apologize for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Add gender and age to your Person class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Person {

    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private String gender;


    public Person() {}

    public Person(long id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

While making request from Postman, include the `age` and `gender` as keys in `x-www-form-urlencoded`. 
By default, the value of integer is `0` and value for String is empty string.
In  your method to handle the request, check the values for `gender` and `age`.
If the values are provided in the request, then use the setters of `Person` class to set the values accordingly.

Suppose the following is your method to handle the request :

```
@POST
@Path("/AddPerson")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)

public String addPerson(@FormParam("id") long id, 
    @FormParam("firstName") String firstName,
    @FormParam("lastName") String lastName, 
    @FormParam("age") int age, 
    @FormParam("gender") String gender) {

    Person person = new Person(id,firstName,lastName);

    if(age != 0) {
        person.setAge(age);
    }

    if(!gender.equals("")) {
        person.setGender(gender)
    }

    // Assuming that PersonService class has the addPerson method
    PersonService.addPerson(1,person)

    return "Person with id "+ id + " added";

}
```

Comment: "By default, [..] value for String is empty string." - um, no. By default, value of a String is null.

Comment: @Anand Undavia I think this is a roundabout way of accomplishing something I need to get done while still processing JSON formatted requests. Is there no way to do similar in JSON?

Comment: @eis `gender.equals("")` is true when the values is not passed and false when the value is passed; however, `gender == null` is false in both the cases

Comment: @viviboox3 I did not get "I need to get done while still processing JSON formatted requests". Can you please elaborate more ?!

Comment: @AnandUndavia I'm sorry I thought I mentioned it. I apologize!

Comment: @AnandUndavia I guess you should mention in the answer then that though value for String is by default null normally, in this context mapper initializes it with empty string (assuming it is so). It is worth mentioning if the mapper doesn't differentiate between not sending the value and sending an empty string as value.

Comment: My team just discussed optional fields in context of updates and we decided that even optional fields should be present to avoid ambiguous situations when user of the API wants to preserve old value and therefore does not send a new one but we on the server treat missing values as permission to fill with defaults, which is not what user expected. So, if user wants to nullify an optional field, it should be specified explicitly as null, but all fields should be present during an update.